# Retrieving Bytes data from boost::asio: array

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to retrieve data from boost array with Bytes data which should at the end be 2 double.
I don't why but I can't make the conversion of the buffer to a readable format here is my attempt :

```
boost::array<void*, 1024> arr;
boost::system::error_code error_2;
socket_2.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(arr), error_2);  
for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++) { std::cout << arr[k]; }
```

I don't understand how to retrieve the data from arr, memcpy is not accepted for instance.

Comment: Please read the [tour] to the end, and inform yourself at our [help] what and how you can ask here!

Comment: You are passing an array of void pointers and expecting some kind of readable buffer in return?

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, whatever you do will amount to memcpy. But you can make things more elegant:

```
boost::array<double, 4096 / sizeof(double)> arr;

boost::system::error_code ec;

size_t n = s.read_some(asio::buffer(arr), ec);

for (size_t i = 0; i < (n / sizeof(double)); ++i) {
    std::cout << arr[i];
}
```

If you already have a raw buffer, consider [`asio::buffer_cast<>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_cast.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you, it works, I retrieve the info, thank you, I am sorry for the misteake, I was not able to identify what was wrong..